# How to get file attachment from "When a HTTP request is received" Trigger Action in Power Automate

Tags: json, triggers, power-automate

I have a Flow with a trigger action of "When a HTTP request is received" like this...

[image: Trigger Action]

I am posting file attachments to this trigger's endpoint.  The post request contains the file(s) data.
[image: Trigger result]

When I download the result of the trigger action OUTPUTS I get JSON similar to below (the $content items have been shortened)...

```
{"headers":{"Connection":"Keep-Alive","Accept":"application/json,text/json,text/x-json,text/javascript,application/xml,text/xml","Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Host":"prod-122.westeurope.logic.azure.com","User-Agent":"RestSharp/106.11.4.0","Content-Length":"753417","Content-Type":"multipart/form-data; boundary=-----------------------------28947758029299"},"queries":{"test":"hello"},"body":{"$content-type":"multipart/form-data; boundary=-----------------------------28947758029299","$content":"LS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLTI4OTQ3NzU4MDI5Mjk5DQpDb250ZW50LURpc3Bvc2l0aW9uOiBmb3JtLWRhdGE7IG5hbWU9ImZpbGUiOyBmaWxlbmFtZT0iQXBwbGljYXRpb25Gb3JtLnBkZiINCkNvbnRlbnQtVHl............................LS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tMjg5NDc3NTgwMjkyOTktLQ0K","$multipart":[{"headers":{"Content-Disposition":"form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"ApplicationForm.pdf\"","Content-Type":"application/octet-stream"},"body":{"$content-type":"application/octet-stream","$content":"JVBERi0xLjYNJeLjz9MNCjc4NTIgMCBvYmoNPDwvRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlL0ZpcnN0IDY0L0xlbmd0aCAxMjY5L04gNy9UeXBlL............................KueM5w8e6Pn+97QzzOIYfrfxK8jWTtj/A/Ng3ICzBCf42CWjM6AKTAEa0SxPj2gzYwPdhN/ywmwFzwK5porhl1rH2loW33X7Mtbo3n8+tuRk1Eo6w3V1ZHt/wqsQ78X+k9hPwS9Afu30K+HjQyrt4DPg9sxugP2ejLPerIiszvmw55nuAj+5/bgdIYNlx02zJ4GbjDs6jXs/LphDqffmcboneY0rU/uFuifhz4EIqo="}}]}}
```

How do I reference the file(s) that were posted to the trigger for further processing e.g. to save them to SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

When posting a single file the triggerBody() can be used in further actions as the file content.  This only works with single files.